# SSRS Show only 1 tablix row

Tags: reporting-services

I'm working on something right that should only show e.g. the fifth element of a dataset. So I made sure the dataset is sorted correctly (alphabetically on title) and then I use this piece of code to give each row an incremental number.

```
public counter As Integer = 0

Function SetNumber()
 counter = counter + 1
 return counter
end Function
```

So the data would look something like this:

```
1 | Africa
2 | America
3 | Antarctica
4 | Asia
5 | Europe
6 | Oceania
```

After that I go to the Row Visibility of my detail row and choose to hide/show the row based on an expression. The expression I'm currently using is:

```
=iif(Fields!Increment.Value = 5, False, True)
```

With this expression ALL of the tablix-rows are hidden. If I switch the 'False' and 'True' values like this:

```
=iif(Fields!Increment.Value = 5, True, False)
```

Only the fifth row is hidden and all the rest is visible.

Does anyone know why my expression doesn't work or how I can make this functionality work.

EDIT "Query that gets data":

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>Continents</ListName>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
  </ViewFields>
  <Query>
    <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="True"/>
    </OrderBy>
  </Query>
</RSSharePointList>
```

To this query I added a calculated field called 'Increment' that uses following expression:

```
=Code.SetNumber()
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to do this on your query/on the database. Would this be possible? Can you show us our query please?

Comment: @user2900970 I get the data from a SharePoint List but I'll put it up in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Thanks to user2900970 I realised that I shouldn't try to show the one item but hide all the other.

So with this expression I only get the 1 item I wanted:

```
=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) <> 5, True, False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to hide rows with Increment.Value higher then 5. Therefore use

```
=IIf(Fields!Increment.Value <= 5, False, True)
```

Easier would be to remove the calculated field and use [RowNumber()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225(v=sql.100).aspx) instead.

```
=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) <= 5, False, True)
```

Comment: This is a better solution than what I have atm but I would like an expression that gives ONLY the fifth item. This shows the first five items instead of only the fifth. Btw: thanks for the rownumber tip :)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!